# Flink RabbitMQ Correlation ID

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I´m trying to understand how to use high availability in Flink with RabbiMQ, using Correlation Ids and enabling Checkpoints, but it is no working. My Producer code:

```
connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

String corrId = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
BasicProperties props = new AMQP.BasicProperties().builder().correlationId(corrId).build();

channel.queueDeclare("flink-poc", true, false, false, null);
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(500); //Queue of messages to be sent to rabbitmq
Message msg = null;
while ((msg = queue.takeMessage()) != null) 
    channel.basicPublish("", "flink-poc", props, mapper.writeValueAsBytes(msg));
channel.close();
connection.close();
```

Consumer code:

```
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment
            .getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setBufferTimeout(100);
env.enableCheckpointing(1000,CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE); // start a checkpoint every 1000 ms
env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

RabbitSource<Message> rabbitSource = new RabbitSource<Message>(Host, 5672, username, pass,  "flink-poc", VirtualHost, true, schema);
messages = env.addSource(rabbitSource, TypeInformation.of(Message.class)
```

With this code, no ACK is returned to RabbitMQ. Any help is appreciated.

**Update:** With a prefetch (`channel.basicQos(15);`), it starts working, but with a very low rate. Is there any way to improve it? If `setStreamTimeCharacteristic` is deactivated, the results are ordered and improves the rate by 10 times, but still very low rate, how is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the same correlationId for all messages, you must use a new one for every message. From https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/rabbitmq/RMQSource.html 'usesCorrelationId - Whether the messages received are supplied with a unique id to deduplicate messages (in case of failed acknowledgments). Only used when checkpointing is enabled.'

Comment: Thank you j s, I was so obsessed watching the rest of the code and the API that I did not notice more important detail.